# Dynamically filling an anchor href using an img src with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I'm trying to grab the SRC of an image, wrap it in an anchor which then uses the SRC of the img as it's HREF, I've so far got the following code, but I'm a bit stuck as to how to finish it off, any ideas?

```
$('#detail img').wrap(function() {
return '<a href="" rel="one" class="fancybox" />';
  });

$('#detail img a').attr('src',$('#detail img').attr('src'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#detail img').wrap(function() {
    return '<a href="' + this.src + '" rel="one" class="fancybox" />';
});
```

By the way, if you can modify initial HTML it's better then doing this with JS.

Comment: Thanks, wish I could edit the HTML, would have made it easier :P

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#detail img').wrap(function() {
    return '<a href="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" rel="one" class="fancybox" />';
});
```

Your second line would always use only the *first* `img a` found.  Also, `img a` is not a valid selector anyway since `a` cannot be a child of `img`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function, `this` refers to the current element (the specific `<img>`), so you could do this:

```
$('#detail img').wrap(function() {
    return '<a href="' + this.src + '" rel="one" class="fancybox" />';
});
```